# wildlfy-maven-plugin ignoring path to deploy file

Tags: java, maven, deployment, wildfly

I'm trying to configure the `wildfly-maven-plugin` in order to get a specific package from the filesystem and deploy it. But it is ignoring my configuration. I'm using the `1.2.0.Final` version of the plugin. What is wrong with my configurations?

The plugin is configured as follow

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <configuration>
                        <targetDir>${project.build.directory}</targetDir>
                        <fileName>${ejb.fileName}.jar</fileName>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I execute `widlfly:deploy`and the following error is reported

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-
plugin:1.2.0.Final:deploy (default-cli) on project cotacao-service:
Execution default-cli of goal org.wildfly.plugins:wildfly-maven-
plugin:1.2.0.Final:deploy failed: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: 
C:\apps\my-app\target\my-app-service-1.0.0.jar -> [Help 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out my mistake. The correct configuration is as follow

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${wildfly.plugin.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <filename>${ejb.fileName}.jar</filename>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```